# sync between mysql and sql server for multiple users

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sqlite

I am developing a android application. I have used xampp server for making use of mysql.When i run the app it should sync with mysql and retreive values and store it in sqlite. I tries this example in the link http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/ . In the same way i developed the code,but in the example as in the link which i used has a column called syncsts in mysql to keep track of sync.But the problem is sync gets updated when one user uses the app and the status gets updated.Again if the other user uses the app then sync does not happens.

My doubt is

1. I want to sync in such a way that when multiple user use the app sync between the mysql and sqlite should happen everytime and multiple users should access the app.How do i modify my code for that.
2. I am using localhost here,problem is runs well with emulator but when tried with real device doesnt work.Only when the pc and mobile are in same network it works.I want to make multiple users use the app with different network.How do i do this.please help

My code is

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
TextView update,updating;
Button btn1,btn2;
HashMap<String, String> queryValues;
DBController controller = new DBController(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
     RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

     client.post("http://192.168.1.104/website/getdbrowcount.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) 
            {
                System.out.println(response);
                try
                {                 
                    Log.d("home", "success");
                     // Create JSON object out of the response sent by getdbrowcount.php
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("home", obj.toString());
                    System.out.println(obj.get("count"));           
                    // If the count value is not zero, 
                    if(obj.getInt("count") != 0)
                    {
                        Log.d("home", "count not equal to zero");
                        AlertDialog.Builder myalert=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        myalert.setTitle("New product data available");
                        Log.d("home", "count");
                        myalert.setMessage("New product data is available.Would you like to download and update?");
                        myalert.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                // Transfer data from remote MySQL DB to SQLite on Android and perform Sync
                                 syncDB();
                                 update.setText("Started syncing to server");
                                 btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }); 


                        myalert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                               
                                 update.setText("The update has been cancelled. Please update via Settings to work"
                                        + " with latest Sonetonix product data");
                                 btn1.setEnabled(true);
                                 btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                                 btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                        });
                        myalert.show();
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        Log.d("home", "count is equal to zero"); 
                        update.setText("New Products are not available. Please keep updating for the new products..");
                        btn1.setEnabled(true);
                        btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                 } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }

            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,String     content) 
            {

}
      });

}

public void  syncDB()
{
    Log.d("home", "db sync");

    // Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
 // Http Request Params Object
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    client.post("http://192.168.1.104/website/getusers.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() 
    {
        @Override

      public void onSuccess(String response)

        {

            // Update SQLite DB with response sent by getusers.php
            updatesqlite(response);
        }



        // When error occured
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) 
        {

         }
   }); 

    }

public void  updatesqlite(String response)
{

    Log.d("home",response);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersynclist;
    usersynclist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    // Create GSON object
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try
    {
        // Extract JSON array from the response
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
        System.out.println(arr.length());
     // If no of array elements is not zero
        if(arr.length() != 0)
        {            
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
            {
                // Get JSON object
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                System.out.println(obj.get("productId"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("category"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("subcategory"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("mountingstyle"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("products"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("description"));

             // DB QueryValues Object to insert into SQLite
                queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
                queryValues.put("productId", obj.get("productId").toString());
                queryValues.put("category", obj.get("category").toString());
                queryValues.put("subcategory", obj.get("subcategory").toString());
                queryValues.put("mountingstyle", obj.get("mountingstyle").toString());
                queryValues.put("products", obj.get("products").toString());
                queryValues.put("description", obj.get("description").toString());

                // Insert User into SQLite DB
                controller.insertUser(queryValues);

                Log.d("home","inserted properly");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Add status for each User in Hashmap
                Log.d("home",map.toString());

                map.put("products", obj.get("products").toString());
                map.put("status", "1"); 
                usersynclist.add(map);

                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------" + usersynclist); 
                Log.d("home",map.toString());
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                      @Override
                      public void run() 
                      {
                        //Do something after 100ms

                      }
                    }, 4000);
            }

         // Inform Remote MySQL DB about the completion of Sync activity by passing Sync status of Users
            updatesyncsts(gson.toJson(usersynclist));

         // Reload the Main Activity
            reloadActivity();
        } 

    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}


// Method to inform remote MySQL DB about completion of Sync activity
public void updatesyncsts(String json)
{

     System.out.println(json);
     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
     RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
     params.put("syncsts", json);
     System.out.println(params);
     // Make Http call to updatesyncsts.php with JSON parameter which has Sync statuses of Users
        client.post("http://192.168.1.104/website/updatesyncsts.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response)
            {
                Log.d("home",response);
                btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn1.setEnabled(true);
                btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }  

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content)
            {

            }

      });
 }

// Reload MainActivity
public void reloadActivity()
{
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(objIntent);
    update.setText("Updated successfully");
}

}
```

DBController.java

```
public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SonetonixProducts.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public DBController(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("home",DATABASE_NAME);

}

@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) 
{

    String query;
    query="CREATE TABLE guide (slno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, productId INTEGER, category TEXT, subcategory TEXT, mountingstyle TEXT, products TEXT, description TEXT )";
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     database.execSQL(query);
     Log.d("home","table created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String query;
    query= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS guide";
    database.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(database);
}

public void insertUser(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) 

    {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("home",database.toString());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("productId", queryValues.get("productId"));
        values.put("category", queryValues.get("category"));
        values.put("subcategory", queryValues.get("subcategory"));
        values.put("mountingstyle", queryValues.get("mountingstyle"));
        values.put("products", queryValues.get("products"));
        values.put("description", queryValues.get("description"));
        database.insert("guide", null, values);
        database.close(); 
        Log.d("home","inserted");
    }

   public ArrayList<String> getAllUsers() 
   {
   ArrayList<String> usersList;
   usersList = new ArrayList<String>();
   String selectQuery = "SELECT category,subcategory FROM guide";
   SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   Log.d("home", cursor.toString());
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {                                                        
           usersList.add(cursor.getString(0));


       }while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   database.close();
   return usersList;
}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getUsers() {
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;
   usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   String selectQuery = "SELECT category,subcategory FROM guide";
   SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();             
           map.put(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
           usersList.add(map);

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
   database.close();
   return usersList;
 }

}
```

How do i achieve this.Please help with exaplanation

Comment: There is *way too much* code here. Figure out where in the code your problem lies and then only show us that.

Comment: I am using local host for the app but want to make it accessible to multiple users through different networks.I have used xampp here. How can that be done

Comment: There seems to be another problem, you create a user list from category and subcategory? Do you want to store the products the user has downloaded? Working with IDs could make everything simpler. You need to create a 2nd table because each user can have several products, so that you have one with the products and one with the (ids of the) products the user has.

Comment: Let me tell that clearly, i want to reterive the values from the mysql database and store into android sqlite.once they are stored in the sqlite when the user runs the app next time and if new products are available only then new updates should appear else should not. how do i do this without syncsts

Comment: please anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your web service and database on Various free hosting websites like [https://www.2freehosting.com](https://www.2freehosting.com/) and after hosting you can provide the URL of web service in android. Then you can access database and web service on any network you are on.

**Edit 1:**

And for the issue or efficient sync of data to your application  periodically check out : https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html